# Как мне совмещать учёбу (надо по средам ходить с 11:55 до 15:00-16:00) и работу джуниор-фронтендером?

Tags: frontend

Я учусь в колледже, мне туда надо ходить по средам и я там нахожусь с 11:55 до 15:00-16:00.
Возможно в январе-феврале или весной будут какие-то экзамены, и мне надо будет иногда чаще ходить туда.
Я хочу устроиться на работу в веб-студию удалённо джуниор фронтенд разработчиком.

До поступления в колледж я работал в веб-студии фронтендером, там был график с 10:30 до 19:00, 5/2 (понедельник-пятница).
Обычно в веб-студиях у фронтедеров примерно такой график.

Я верстаю лэндинги быстро, кроссбраузерно, адаптивно. Ещё я делаю одностраничные приложения на Реакте.
Знаю: html, css, sass, pug, javascript (es6), npm, gulp, react, figma, немного php.
В процессе работы я выучу ещё какие-нибудь технологии (typescript, redux и т.д.).

Я хочу закончить колледж и поступить в вуз (на ускоренное обучение), и хочу сейчас параллельно работать, чтоб денег на жизнь хватало.
Вот как мне быть в этой ситуации? Как мне совместить учёбу и работу?
(Проблема в занятой среде каждую неделю и в будущих экзаменах (это занятые дни). Я хочу придумать как же мне всё-таки совместить учёбу с работой,
но пока что я не придумал)

Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: 1) выставить приоритеты 2) понизить приоритеты для ненужной фигни 3) скорректировать сон

Comment: Кроме среды и будущих экзаменов, у меня всё остальное время свободно.

Comment: тогда в чем вообще проблема то?

Comment: Такие вещи обговаривается с работодателем и почти всегда находится компромисс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всегда посещать занятия по средам и выполнять задания по учебе (+1 день). Предупредить робатодателя что ты учишься. Скажи ему  что тебе важна учеба и тебе нужно мин. 2 дня в неделю (среда, воскресенье) ей уделять, для работадателя это вообще 1 день получается так как воскресенье все ровно выходной. Главное поговори со своим работадателем предупреди его об о все нюансах учебы (сессия, модули и т д ) что ты раз в несколько месяцев на неделю будешь занят учебой. Если работа нормальная и начальник тоже то тебя поймут и даже подержат так как все понимают что учеба важна, а если не понимают то не нужна тебе такая работа. Поработать ты всегда успеешь, пока есть возможность учится учись. Главное будь честен со всеми и не в коем случае не ври на работе что ты свободен и можешь делать почти все. Ставь свои цели выше других